# Should "other interest" outbound link be nofollow?

Tags: blog, nofollow

I am usually blogging about programming issues in my blog. Occasionally I like to write guest post in the "travel" category. I like to link the post from my blog as *Other interest*. Both are entirely different categories. Should I give the `rel="nofollow"` to those links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if categories are different, I think you shouldn't add the `rel="nofollow"` attribute to your links. As you said, you like to link the post from your blog, thus it's a natural link and search engines like natural links.

Answer (score -1):

If you would be able to link your website to a travel category it must be somewhat relevant. Adding a `nofollow` tag could help you better from avoiding Google algorithm penalties as well.